# Python pandas DF question : trying to drop a column but nothing happens (df.drop) - code also runs without any errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to delete a column called `Rank` but nothing happens. The remaining code all executes without any issue but the column itself remains in the output file. I've highlighted the part of the code that is not working.

```
def read_csv():

    file = "\mona" + yday+".csv"
    #df=[]
    df = pd.read_csv(save_path+file,skiprows=3,encoding = "ISO-8859-1",error_bad_lines=False)
    return df



# replace . with / in column EPIC
def tickerchange():
    df=read_csv()
    df['EPIC'] = df['EPIC'].str.replace('.','/')
    return df

def consolidate_AB_listings():
    df=tickerchange()
    Aline = df.loc[(df['EPIC'] =='RDSA'),'Mkt Cap (àm)']
    Bline = df.loc[(df['EPIC'] =='RDSB'),'Mkt Cap (àm)']
    df.loc[(df['EPIC'] =='RDSA'),'Mkt Cap (àm)']= float(Aline) + float(Bline)
    df = df.loc[(df.Ind != 'I/E')]
    df = df.loc[(df.Ind != 'FL')]
    df = df.loc[(df.Ind != 'M')]
    df = df.loc[(df.EPIC != 'RDSB')]
    return df  

def ranking_mktcap():
    df = consolidate_AB_listings()
    df['Rank']= df['Mkt Cap (àm)'].rank(ascending=False)
    df = df.loc[(df.Rank != 1)]
    df['Rank1']= df['Mkt Cap (Em)'].rank(ascending=False)
    ## This doesn't seem to work
    df = df.drop(df['Security'], 1)
    return df

def save_outputfile():
    #df = drop()
    df = ranking_mktcap()
    df.to_csv(r'S:\Index_Analytics\UK\Index Methodology\FTSE\Py_file_download\MonitoredList.csv', index=False)
    print("finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    read_csv()
    tickerchange()
    consolidate_AB_listings()
    ranking_mktcap()
    save_outputfile()
```

Comment: `df = df.drop(['Security'], axis=1)`

Comment: Most pandas methods do not mutate the frame but return a copy. Add `inplace=True` to mutate the frame.

Comment: @erip that makes an unnecessary copy

Comment: @MaxNoe Every other line of the code makes copies... One thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

[DataFrame.drop()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) takes the following: `DataFrame.drop(self, labels=None, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')`.

When you call `df = df.drop(df['Security'], 1)` it's using `df['security']` as the labels to drop. And the `1` is being passed through the `axis` parameter.

If you want to drop the column `'Security'` then you'd want to do:

```py
df = df.drop('Security', axis=1)
# this is same as
df = df.drop(labels='Security', axis=1)
# you can also specify the column name directly, like this
df = df.drop(columns='Security')
```

Note: the `columns=` parameter can take a single lable (str) like above, or can take a list of column names.

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing

```
 df = df.drop(df['Security'], 1)
```

By

```
df.drop(['Security'],axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and all I did was add **inplace = True**

So it will be `df = df.drop(df['Security'], 1, inplace = True)`